# Why would I have a 4624 (logon) and 4634 (logoff) event at the exact same second?

Tags: security, windows-7, windows-event-log

I'm investigating who was using one of our company computer's a certain time.  While I was looking through the 4624 / 4634 events in the event log, I found that several times throughout the day there was a 4624 (logon) followed immediately by a 4634 (logoff).  According to the event time, they happened at the exact same second.  I also checked and both the logon and logoff have the same Logon ID.

The logon type for both is `7`.  As far as I understand, that means this person unlocked their computer and then immediately relocked it.  Many times during the day.

What would cause these logs?

Comment: There are 1000 milliseconds in a second.  The logging reports time in DD:MM:YY HH:MM:SS.  Outlook has been known to interact with interactive logon and trigger events.

Comment: @Colyn1337 I know it could have been separated by milliseconds.  I don't think it's reasonable that a *user* would have unlocked/relocked a computer only milliseconds apart.  Also, Outlook is not installed on the problem computer.

Comment: There may be other programs trying with session lock/unlock (say something like TeamViewer?). Did you try looking for the processes run by the user?

Comment: @AlexMazzariol How do I find what processes were run?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding; afaik, Windows does not keep track of programs run in the past. I meant, did you try looking at the running processes (e.g. with `tasklist`) to check if there was some remote-access tool running? They are likely to mess with session lock/unlock.

Comment: @AlexMazzariol There are no remote access programs on the computer.